# How to find if a specific function is being used within another function

Tags: r

I want to be able to find whether the function `.Deprecated` is being used within a certain function, say `my.fun`. As an example:

```
my.fun <- function (...) {
  .Deprecated("my_fun")
  my_fun(...)
}
```

At the moment I am using

```
grepl(".Deprecated", as.character(body(getFromNamespace("my.fun", "mypackage"))))
```

Which works fine, and in the above example it returns

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE  FALSE
```

But if I have the word `.Deprecated` as a simple character string within a function, this will also be picked up. I am aware of the `mvbutils::foodweb()` and `mvbutils::calleer.of()` functions but they only work if I explicitly define my own `.Deprecated` function. Is anyone aware of an elegant way to search for just a function, and not a character string?

Comment: Have you tried `is.function`?

Comment: `grepl(".Deprecated(", as.character(body(getFromNamespace("my.fun", "mypackage"))), fixed = TRUE)`?

Comment: @Roland Will fail for e.g. `function () 'Usage: .Deprecated("my_fun")'`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you are correct. Your answer below seems much more robust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than doing a string search, a robust solution must inspect the *syntax* of the function body. Luckily, R makes this relatively easy:

```
variables = all.names(body(myfunction))
'.Deprecated' %in% variables
```

One caveat is that this doesn’t test whether `.Deprecated` actually refers to `base::.Deprecated`; *any* use of the symbol as a variable/function name will show up in the above. However, finding out which function a symbol refers to is not possible in general without actually executing the function, so this is as good as it gets, short of executing all functions and tracing their function calls.

The best you can do is get the list of names used in a function, and get their definitions in the context in which the function was defined. This can be seen as an *okay* heuristic: if your function uses `.Deprecated`, and that symbol is defined in the context in which the function was defined, then this will yield the correct definition. However, it would for instance fail in the following circumstances:

- False positive:

  ```
  f1 = function () {
      .Deprecated = 42
  }
  ```
- False negative:

  ```
  f2 = function () {
      x = get('.Deprecated', mode = 'function')
      x("f1")
  }
  ```

So use with caution.

```
calls_function = function (f, target, target_name = deparse(substitute(target_name))) {
    find_definition = function (candidates)
        mget(candidates, environment(target), mode = 'function')

    resolves_to_target = function (candidates)
        sapply(find_definition(candidates), identical, target)

    variables = unique(all.names(body(f)))
    candidates = grep(target_name, variables, fixed = TRUE)
    length(candidates) > 0 && any(resolves_to_target(variables[candidates]))
}
```

Usage:

```
calls_function(f1, .Deprecated)
```

Note that the function names are passed as *unquoted* arguments; if you want to pass `base::.Deprecated`, you need to also provide the “unqualified” name as the third argument:

```
calls_function(f1, base::.Deprecated, '.Deprecated')
```

Comment: This is great! It is a shame you cannot test whether it is indeed `base::.Deprecated` or `mypackage::.Deprecated` but for my purposes, this works really well.

Comment: @Natty_E Actually you can go a bit further, see updated answer. It’s a bit tricky but it should essentially work, and it might be a nice utility for other people as well.

Comment: @Konnrad Rudolph this is great. I am currently working on something quite neat which will hopefully be of use to other so I will link you to my blog here when I am "done"